# Smoothness wrt every altas is equivalent to smoothness wrt the maximal altas

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

> Let $(M,A)$ and $(N,B)$ be smooth manifolds and suppose that $f:(M,A') \to (N,B')$ be continuous, where A' and B' are maximal atlases of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Show that $f$ is smooth if and only if $f$ is smooth as a function  $f:(M,A) \to (N,B)$.

**My attempt:** If $f:(M,A') \to (N,B')$ is smooth then $f:(M,A) \to (N,B)$ is also smooth since  the atlas $A'$ includes the atlas $A$ and likewise for $B'$ and $(N,B)$. For the other direction, since $f:(M,A) \to (N,B)$ is smooth for every choice of charts in $A$ and $B$ then it is smooth for every choice of charts in  $A'$, $B'$, because that atlas $A'$ is exactly the maximal atlas that be built by adding charts that are compatible to all charts in $A$ and $B'$ is built in the same way from $B$. If I am on the right track how to make these rigorous? Also, according to the definition of the book, local smoothness of f with respect to two charts $(U, \phi) \in A$ and $(V, \psi) \in B$ means $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U) \to \psi(V)$ is smooth ; how to generalize this definition so to include the question in the exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is is correct. Just to write it in a more rigorous way:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $f:(M,A') \to (N,B')$ is smooth. It means that $f$ is continuous,  and,  for all $(U,\phi) \in A'$ and for all $(V,\psi) \in B'$, $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U \cap f^{-1}(V)) \to \psi(V)$ is $C^\infty$.

Now since $A \subseteq A'$ and $B \subseteq B'$, we have that $f$ is continuous,  and,  for all $(U,\phi) \in A$ and for all $(V,\psi) \in B$, $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi(U \cap f^{-1}(V)) \to \psi(V)$ is $C^\infty$. So $f:(M,A) \to (N,B)$ is smooth.

$(\Leftarrow)$. Suppose $f:(M,A) \to (N,B)$ is smooth. Then $f$ is continuous.
Given any  $(U',\phi') \in A'$ and $(V',\psi') \in B'$, let us prove that   $\psi' \circ f \circ {\phi'}^{-1}: \phi'(U' \cap f^{-1}(V')) \to \psi'(V')$ is $C^\infty$.

Given any $p \in U'\cap f^{-1}(V')$, there are $(U,\phi) \in A$ and $(V,\psi) \in B$, such that $p \in U$ and $f(p) \in V$. So $p \in U\cap f^{-1}(V)$. So, $U'\cap f^{-1}(V')\cap U\cap f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set in $M$, $p \in U'\cap f^{-1}(V')\cap U\cap f^{-1}(V)$, and
$$  (\psi'\circ \psi^{-1}) \circ (\psi\circ f \circ \phi^{-1})\circ (\phi'\circ\phi)^{-1}: \phi'(U' \cap f^{-1}(V') \cap U \cap f^{-1}(V) ) \to \psi'(V') $$
is $C^\infty$.
But
$$ \psi' \circ f \circ {\phi'}^{-1}|_{\phi'(U' \cap f^{-1}(V') \cap U \cap f^{-1}(V) )} = (\psi'\circ \psi^{-1}) \circ (\psi\circ f \circ \phi^{-1})\circ (\phi'\circ\phi)^{-1}$$

So, given any $p \in U'\cap f^{-1}(V')$, $\psi' \circ f \circ {\phi'}^{-1}$ is $C^\infty$ in a neighborhood of $\phi'(p)$. So, $\psi' \circ f \circ {\phi'}^{-1}: \phi'(U' \cap f^{-1}(V')) \to \psi'(V')$ is $C^\infty$.

So, given any  $(U',\phi') \in A'$ and $(V',\psi') \in B'$, we have prove that   $\psi' \circ f \circ {\phi'}^{-1}: \phi'(U' \cap f^{-1}(V')) \to \psi'(V')$ is $C^\infty$. So $f:(M,A') \to (N,B')$ is smooth.